# Set current multiple value in selectize JS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, selectize.js

I have problem in selectize JS when set current value is multiple value. I set from Ajax response in Json format, here is my code.

```
$(".rule_list").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'getruledata,
          dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $selectz[0].selectize.setValue(data[0].control_country);
        })
      });
```

Here my HTML code

```
<select id="select-country" placeholder="Pick a countries..."></select>
```

And here code for selectize

```
var $selectz = $('#select-country').selectize({
        maxItems: null,
        valueField: 'iso',
        labelField: 'nice_name',
        searchField: 'nice_name',
        options: {!! $country !!},
        create: false,
      });
```

Here my value format from Json response

```
[{"id":2,"name":"XSA 2","user_id":"3","control_device":"Mobile","control_country":"US,CA","offer_id":"2","rule_id":"1","status":"2"}]
```

I'm stuck in this steps, if `"control_country":"US,CA"` (multiple value) not working when set current value to input form, but if `"control_country":"US"` (single value) working correctly

Answer (score 7):

You can set multiple values to selectize like this:

```
$selectz[0].selectize.setValue([optionid,optionid]);
```

So in your example it should be:

```
$selectz[0].selectize.setValue(["US","CA"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method `addItem(value, silent)`. As explained in the [docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_items), addItem "selects" items, where passing true to "silent" will apply the change to the original input.